# Writing to a files raw disk sectors

Tags: c++, c, database

I'm working on a OS portable database server and I want to know what is the best way to read/write to a index file disk sectors without locking the entire file. My database disk manager have a bitmap that keep track of where all used/unused the sectors are inside the index file. Also, is there a OS portable way of doing this?

Comment: You don't need to know anything about raw disk sectors to do this.  Just use the functions that control seeking or I/O offset.  e.g. `fseek` and `ftell`.

Comment: That's what drivers are for, only drivers know about such low details

Comment: @BenVoigt Can a multiple threads write to the same file at the same time when I use fseek and ftell?

Comment: if you want predictable results, threads cannot be writing to the same place in the file at the same time. For example if there's 'A' in the file, one thread writes 'B' and another 'C' - at the same time - there's no way to know what will be the result in the end, 'B' or 'C'

Comment: @Drakosha My disk manager make sure that two threads don't write to the same sector at the same time.

Comment: As I see fseek does not guarante that I get the start position of a sector. When you create a index file you want to make sure that each node in the index tree starts at the start of a disk sector. fseek only positions the file pointer from the start of the file and I don't think that the file system always start a new file at the start of a block. I can't find any documentation that ffseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET) is guaranteed to point to the first byte in a disk sector. Also, most file systems scatters a single file over the whole disk which could also cause me problems.

Comment: ... so fseek(pFile, 1024, SEEK_SET) may be at the middle of a disk sector and not at the start of the disk block even though the disk block size is 512 bytes.

Comment: There's very little practical danger that byte offset 0 of a file is not at a block boundary, but you're probably right that there is no standard that guarantees it.  Make sure you write your code using a good abstraction layer for the disk I/O, so that if you find you need to change something, you have only a small quantity of code to rewrite.  There's guaranteed to be no portable way to find out if a disk file offset of 0 is on a block boundary; the question cannot even be asked of the O/S in POSIX.

Comment: @Inge: It doesn't matter whether `fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET)` is the first byte of a disk sector.  (Realistically it will be, except for very small files where the contents are stored inside the parent directory)  You just need to make sure things don't overlap.  For performance reasons, you might want to use memory-mapped files and pay attention to the alignment constraints imposed by `mmap`.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's important that an index node fits excactly inside a disk sector so that it's only one i/o operation when I do index node CRUD operations.

Comment: ..just wanted to add that I'm talking about physical I/O operations and not logical ones.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen: sufficiently big files will always be stored starting at a block boundary, the exception is for very small files which may be tail-packed on some FSs.

Comment: @ninjalj I don't know if all OS's guarantee that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...read/write to a index file disk sectors without locking the entire file.

You can lock just the portion (of the file) you are writing to. Under Windows, this would be accomplished using [LockFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). BTW, why is it important not to lock the whole file? Your server will have exclusive access to it anyway, and it can manage the locking internally (unless you want a server-less/embedded database while still allowing multiple client connections to it).

To achieve transaction [durability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durability_%28database_systems%29), you'll also need to make sure the data you write doesn't linger in the cache/buffers and is being physically written to the disk at correct times. Under Windows, consider passing FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH (and possibly FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, assuming you do your own cache management) to [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I don't think there are OS-independent APis for any of this - you'll need to do it in a special way under each supported OS. Of course, nothing prevents you from encapsulating OS-specific code and presenting the uniform interface toward the rest of your system.

Comment: `lockf` and `fflush` aren't OS-independent APIs?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm not sure `lockf` can be used on Windows. `fflush` is not enough for durability: not even `fsync` is enough on some systems, you may need `fcntl(F_FULLSYNC)`

Comment: As you I suspect CreateFile is the way to go on WinOS to solve this. Thanks for the durability tip, have never read about that before. Since only one process will access the file at a time I wanted to implement locking in my disk manager bitmap, but I will keep LockFile in mind for later.

Comment: I can confirm that at least on WinOS the way to go is with `CreateFile`, `WriteFile`, `ReadFile`, and `SetFilePointer`. For durability use `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` and `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` or flush the disk file caches manually with `fflush`.